# Nginx : remove 404 logs if response 200 returned after redirection

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404

With Nginx, I intercept 404 errors for some JS file in a folder, and redirect to a PHP script that try to create / return the good file, with response code 200 in case of success.

But Nginx continues to write in error.log because the first attempts return a 404 header.

Can I disable this writing if the redirection leads to a 200 response code ?

My configuration in Nginx for these files :

```
    location /assets/js/minified/ {
            error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404&action=create_js;
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `try_files` is a better fit for your use case

```
location /assets/js/minified/ {
  try_files $uri /index.php?controller=404&action=create_js;
}
```

See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Otherwise (in case you don't like `try_files` for any reason), there is [`log_not_found`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#log_not_found) directive that disables writing 404s into error.log.

Comment: Thanks, `try_files` works perfectly ; why could I not like it ? Some problems with this method ? `log_not_found` isn't a good idea I think, because I want to catch real 404 (returned by my script in case of error)

Comment: There should be no problems w/ `try_files`, it is a perfect and mature mechanism for a kind of problems you faced. Glad you liked it.

Comment: @Doubidou you should accept answers if/when you think they are correct. This is how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I know how StackOverflow works, I was just waiting for confirmation about `try_files` before accept it ;)